# Regex Expression to Find All Digits in a list and dashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, algorithm

I am trying to convert this string '4-6,10-12,16' into a list that looks like this [4,"-",6,10,"-",12,16]. There would be a combination of integers and the special character "-" in the list.

I was trying to use a regex code in python but I could only do it to extract the numbers, however, I need the dashes as well in the list. How can I include dashes with numbers in the list?

Here is my code:

```
interval='4-6,10-12,16'
import re
l=[int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', interval)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
interval='4-6,10-12,16'
import re
l=[int(s) if s.isnumeric() else s for s in re.findall(r'\d+|-', interval)]
l
```

---

**Output:**

```
[4, '-', 6, 10, '-', 12, 16]
```

Comment: You probably don't want that literal `+` in your character set there.

Comment: Also, your `\b` anchors are themselves split by the alternation. You'll need to put the rest into a group and leave those outside

Comment: Really, just `r'\d+|-'` would suffice

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
interval='4-6,10-12,16'
l=[int(s) if all(c.isdigit() for c in s) else '-' for s in re.findall(r'\d+|-', interval)]
print(l) # => [4, '-', 6, 10, '-', 12, 16]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tBqrlT).

*Details*:

- `re.findall(r'\d+|-', interval)` extracts digit sequences or `-` chars
- `int(s) if all(c.isdigit() for c in s) else '-'` either casts a digit sequence to an `int` if the whole match consists of digits, or just returns `-` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Useful functions:

- `str.isdigit` (or `str.isnumeric` or `str.isdecimal`);
- `itertools.groupby` to group adjacent characters that share a characteristic.

```py
from itertools import groupby

def tokenize_digits_and_dashes(s):
    for k, g in groupby(s, key=lambda c: (c.isdigit(), c == '-')):
        if k == (True, False):
            yield int(''.join(g))
        elif k == (False, True):
            yield '-'

print(list(tokenize_digits_and_dashes('4-6,10-12,16')))
# [4, '-', 6, 10, '-', 12, 16]
```

**Alternative approach**

Your string already contains separators in the form of commas `,`. These are useful! Don't ignore them. You can split the list on the separators using `str.split`.

```py
def tokenize_intervals(s):
    for interval in s.split(','):
        i = interval.split('-')
        if len(i) == 2:
            yield tuple(int(''.join(w)) for w in i)
        elif len(i) == 1:
            x = int(''.join(i[0]))
            yield (x, x)

print(list(tokenize_intervals('4-6,10-12,16')))
# [(4, 6), (10, 12), (16, 16)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# By Using Regex #
# -------------- #

import re
interval = '4-6,10-12,16'
s_list = re.findall(r'[\d+]+|-', interval)
x = [int(_) if _.isnumeric() else _ for _ in s_list]
print(x)

# By Using the split method #
# ------------------------- #
final_list = []
for _ in interval.split(','):
    sub_list = _.split('-')
    for i in sub_list:
        if i.isnumeric():
            final_list.append(int(i))
        if sub_list[-1] != I:
            final_list.append('-')
print(final_list)

# By Checking Character By Character #
# ---------------------------------- #
z = ""
s = []
count = 0
for _ in interval:
    count += 1
    if _.isnumeric():
        z += _
        if count == len(interval):
            s.append(int(z))
    elif _ == '-':
        s.append(int(z))
        z = ""
        s.append('-')
    else:
        s.append(int(z))
        z = ""
print(s)
```